# onDraw() method for child class of ImageView not getting called

Tags: android, bitmap, ondraw, invalidation

I have a class `LayeredImageView` extending `ImageView` which I use to create Bitmaps consisting of layers of Bitmaps drawn over each other. The Bitmaps I'm drawing are military units for a game, and one of the Bitmaps I'd like to layer over a unit Bitmap is their health. I switch on the health variable in the `onDraw()` method and draw the appropriate Bitmap.

My problem is that the `onDraw()` method is never getting called (verified with debug messages).

I keep an adapter of my LayeredImageViews in a class `ImageViewAdapter` extending `BaseAdapter`, and in the `getView(...)` method call `imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbIds[position])` with the appropriate Bitmap argument. From what I understand, this should be calling the `invalidate()` method of `LayeredImageView`, which should in turn call `onDraw()`, but like I said, that isn't happening.

Here is the core of the `LayeredImageView` class:

```
public class LayeredImageView extends ImageView{

private static final String TAG = "LayeredImageView";

Context mContext;
int health;

public LayeredImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    health = 0;
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public void setHealth(int health){
    this.health = health;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap healthIcon = null;
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;

    switch(health){
    case 1:
        healthIcon = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.health1, 100, 100);
        break;
    case 2:
        healthIcon = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.health2, 100, 100);
        break;
    }
    if(healthIcon != null){
        width = healthIcon.getWidth();
        height = healthIcon.getHeight();
        x = canvas.getWidth() - width;
        y = canvas.getHeight() - height;
        canvas.drawBitmap(healthIcon, x, y, new Paint());
    }
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

As you can see, I tried implementing the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394450/ondraw-not-being-called), with no luck.

**EDIT**

Here is where the `LayeredImageView` object is instantiated:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayeredImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new LayeredImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(7, 5, 7, 5);
    }
    else{
        imageView = (LayeredImageView) convertView;
    }

    Piece piece = game.getPiece(position % 10, 9-position/10);
    if(piece != null){//here we overlay the health icon if the piece has non-zero health
        imageView.setHealth(piece.getHealth());
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `x = (canvas.getWidth()/2) - (width/2);`
         `y = (canvas.getHeight()/2) - (height/2);`. try this also move all your intiaization and calculations outside `onDraw`. `invalidate` will draw the problem might be in your `onDraw`.

Comment: The problem is that the `onDraw` method isn't even being called at all, so it never gets near those initializations. Any idea why that is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: @Rokatu log soem info and check i am sure `onDraw` is called. its something do with your draw. Log some info like `Log.i("Drawing","on draw called")`;

Comment: No. I put the line `Log.d(TAG,"in onDraw method");` right after the `super.onDraw(canvas)` call and no debug message is printed.

Comment: put it in `onDraw` not in constructor. if you don't see then your view is not getting called. shows us where you use your custom view class or call the constructor.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the call to `super.onDraw(canvas)`, I edited my comment. It is in `onDraw`, this is how I know `onDraw` is not getting called. However, I can verify that other methods in the view are being accessed, such as the `setHealth(...)` method. I will edit the post to show how the view is defined and called. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: log the info in if else of `getView` and check

Comment: Which info should I print out? I checked a simple debug message, and the if clause is being accessed, but the else clause was not in my short test. I forget under which conditions it would be though ...

Comment: Is the view being invalidated somewhere?  Call imageView.invalidate() in getView and see if onDraw doesn't get called.

Comment: Well, my understanding was that `setImageBitmap(...)` is supposed to automatically call `invalidate()`, which calls `onDraw(...)`. However, I have tried calling `invalidate()` manually and no, it still doesn't call the `onDraw(...)` method.